# Number type between 0 and 1

Tags: c++

Is there a natural way to define a number type between 0 and 1? Essentially one could do everything with double, the problem is that I should define some bound checking in some functions and I had the (probably stupid) idea to outsource the bound checking to a class, something like

```
class Probability {

    // the value of the Probability
    double val;

    Probability(double val):value(val){
    // freak out if val > 1 or val < 0
    //...
    //
    };

    // operators such as
    Probability operator + (Probability const & a, Probability const & b){
        double result a.val + b.val;
        if ((result > 1) || (result < 0)){
            // freak out
            result = 0
        }
        return result;
    }
    // ...
    //
}
```

The problem with this approach is probably that it slows down every operation. Is there a faster way of bound checking? I also would like to know how to handle the "freak out" sections in the code above.

Comment: yo can just use a `char` and normalize it for example.

Comment: Wait, I think you got my question wrong... char is only 8 bit. I would like to have 64 bit for double precision just as before

Comment: This is the right place for an `assert`. If someone passes in nonsensical values, blow up and break into the debugger.

Comment: you can go for a 64 bit unsigned int number where 0 is 0.f and the biggnum is your 1. playing with fractions you can get it properly work. But, dont waste time, just use the code you have, it looks proper to me. You can extrat the check into a method and call each time you may want to check the values.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. Consider: `Probability(0.75) + Probability(0.5) - Probability(0.6)`. Ths would "freak out" even if the final result is in [0..1].

Comment: Would it speed up performance, Daniel? I wonder if there is way of doing it without blowing it up with classes, probably with Inline Assembly?

Comment: Henrik: One should place braces, to be formally correct. I would buy that if at least I find out where the program freaks out

Comment: I think you could solve Henrik's case by having binary operator overloads that don't check, but `operator+=`, `operator-=` and `operator=` that actually do the check. Then you could have temporary with a value > 1 (e.g. in the middle of an expression), but no lvalue in such a state. That may be a case where you don't want to implement the binary operators based on the member operators.

Comment: (1) Probabilities do not add like this. (2) A data type where `a - b` can be valid even if `a` is invalid is Big-W-*Weird* (and very very likely not well defined and thus a source of many weird problems to come).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the class `Probability` to enforce the bounds, storing a double internally. If you want operations such as `P(0.75) + P(0.5) - P(0.6)` to work, you can have the operators return a proxy object, which doesn't do the bounds checking. This proxy object would have a conversion operator to `Probability`, and the `Probability` constructor would check the bounds. If you only ever use the `Probability` type directly, and allow temporaries of the form `ProbabilityResultProxy`, you'll get the desired behaviour.

The example below outlines this approach. Obviously there's quite a lot missing that you'd want in a real implementation, but I wanted to focus on a specific solution, rather than providing a complete class.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bebb708d70493720):

```
#include <iostream>

class Probability {
  public:

    Probability(double value) {
        if (value < 0 || value > 1) throw std::runtime_error("Invalid probability");
        value_ = value;
    }

    double value() const { return value_; }

  private:
    double value_;
};

class ProbabilityResultProxy {
  public:
    explicit ProbabilityResultProxy(double p) : value_(p) {}

    double value() const { return value_; }

    operator Probability() {
        return Probability(value_);
    }

  private:
    double value_;
};

ProbabilityResultProxy operator+(const Probability& lhs, const Probability& rhs) {
    return ProbabilityResultProxy(lhs.value() + rhs.value());
}
ProbabilityResultProxy operator+(const ProbabilityResultProxy& lhs, const Probability& rhs) {
    return ProbabilityResultProxy(lhs.value() + rhs.value());
}
ProbabilityResultProxy operator+(const Probability& lhs, const ProbabilityResultProxy& rhs) {
    return ProbabilityResultProxy(lhs.value() + rhs.value());
}
ProbabilityResultProxy operator+(const ProbabilityResultProxy& lhs, const ProbabilityResultProxy& rhs) {
    return ProbabilityResultProxy(lhs.value() + rhs.value());
}

ProbabilityResultProxy operator-(const Probability& lhs, const Probability& rhs) {
    return ProbabilityResultProxy(lhs.value() - rhs.value());
}
ProbabilityResultProxy operator-(const ProbabilityResultProxy& lhs, const Probability& rhs) {
    return ProbabilityResultProxy(lhs.value() - rhs.value());
}
ProbabilityResultProxy operator-(const Probability& lhs, const ProbabilityResultProxy& rhs) {
    return ProbabilityResultProxy(lhs.value() - rhs.value());
}
ProbabilityResultProxy operator-(const ProbabilityResultProxy& lhs, const ProbabilityResultProxy& rhs) {
    return ProbabilityResultProxy(lhs.value() - rhs.value());
}

int main() {
    Probability p1(0.75);
    Probability p2(0.5);
    Probability p3(0.6);

    Probability result = p1 + p2 - p3;
    std::cout << result.value() << "\n";

    try {
        Probability result2 = p1 + p2;
        std::cout << result2.value();
    } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here, the mathematical operators are defined for each combination of `Probability` and `ProbabilityResultProxy`. Each operation returns a proxy object, and the final assignment causes the bounds check to be performed.

---

If you want, you could make the `ProbabilityResultProxy` a private member class of `Probability`, and make the operators friends of `Probability`. This prevents anyone from instantiating the proxy class directly.

Comment: I really like this answer.  It expresses the idea directly in code and leverages the strengths of the type system and compile-time knowledge to encapsulate all the concepts without paying any unnecessary runtime cost.

Answer (score 1):

The "freak out" option is simple: `throw std::invalid_argument`. It doesn't matter that throwing is a bit slow; you're not getting an answer anyway. The upside is that not throwing is fast as the optimizer can assume the non-exception paths are far more likely.

Performance-wise it might be beneficial to have a `IntermediateResult` class such that only the final assignment back to `Probability` is range-checked. This sidesteps the `0.75+0.5-0.6` example.